# How to include App Link in Share-Intent feature in Android

Tags: java, android

I created an android app and suceeded in adding share button and it works great. But the only challenge I'm having now is how to include app download link along side with the textView generated for sharing.
For example
I want to have something like this:

Baby soap that nurtures skin
is the recommended soap
for skin care and viral
treatment etc. *This App can be downloaded from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id*

**This is my Share Java Code**

````
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mDetailTv.getText().toString());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
                startActivity(sendIntent);```



**This is what i tried that didn't work**

//share Copied Text characters via other apps button
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mDetailTv.getText().toString());
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out the App at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+"app_package_name");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
````

Comment: Add your desired text to the string that you are passing via `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: Can you please give me example. thanks in advance

Comment: This is what i tried that didn't show the link. I passed the text object through mDetailTv. Then i want to add App download link below the text content. So i tried this your code which didn't show anything,                                                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.my_share_link)));        please help me.

Comment: "Can you please give me example" -- `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mDetailTv.getText().toString() + " and this is the other text that you want to have appear as well");`

Comment: Yes! Yes!! Yes!!!, It works like charm. @ CommonsWare Thank you sir!